# Photo Album inside an app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, camera, photos

Do any of you know if it's possible to make a Photo Album inside an app? The app that I'm building has a lot of features, one of them is to take a picture, write on top of it, save it, and then mail it if you want. I know the photos go to the Camera Roll Album, but is there a way for them not to go there? If not, then how can I bring them to my app in some sort of thumbnail scroll gallery or something so that I can edit them and resave them?

Important Note: the many features also consume a lot of memory, so I'll have to use the least resources possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios//#/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).

You can also save your photos to the Documents directory as well, it doesn't have to be the Camera Roll or Photo Library.

Comment: how can I save the photos there? and how would I access them? I'm sorry but I've only been using xcode since 3 months ago, so I'm not very skilled.

Comment: Same way you would save and access any file in the Documents directory.

Answer (score 1):

Source code see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I don't think that really works for me, I have to include the features inside the app, scrolling the images so I can see them inside the app